# Database not creating automatically in Grails

Tags: grails

I am working on `grails` project where I am using `MySQL` database. When I use by default `HSQLDB` it creates the database and tables automatically , but in case of `MySQL` I need to create a database manually.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    username = "root"
    password = "root"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sec_grails"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sec_grails"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sec_grails_prod"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any way to create a database in `MySQL` automatically ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. Grails does not create databases except for in the case of the in-memory databases (H2 and HSQLDB). You have to create your database manually. Once created Grails can manage the schema but it can't create the database for you.